# Order of int32_t to uint64_t casting

Tags: c++

Does the C++ standard guarantee whether integer conversion that both widens and casts away the sign will sign-extend or zero-extend?

The quick test:

```
int32_t s = -1;
uint64_t u = s;
```

produces an 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF under Xcode, but is that a defined behavior in the first place?

Comment: Re: "casts away the sign" -- there are no casts involved here. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The conversion here is implicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
uint64_t u = s;
```

[[dcl.init]/17.9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.9) applies which states:

> the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression. A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered.

and if we look in [[conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv), under integral conversions, we have

> Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the destination type.

So what you are guaranteed to have happen is that -1 becomes the largest number possible to represent, -2 is one less then that, -3 is one less then -2 and so on, basically it "wraps around".

---

In fact,

```
unsigned_type some_name = -1;
```

Is the canonical way to create a variable with the maximum value for that unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the standard verbiage in other answers.

But to help you form an intuitive mental model of widening conversions, it is helpful to think of these as a 2-step process:

1. Sign- or zero-extension of the value. If the value is of signed *type*, then sign extension is used. Here `int32_t` is sign-extended to `int64_t`. On x86, the signedness of type detetermines whether [`MOVSX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) or [`MOVZX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) instruction is used.
2. Converting the extended value to the destination type (change of signedness). Here `int64_t` is converted to `uint64_t`. It involves 0 assembly instructions as registers are untyped, the compiler just treats that register, which contains the result of sign extension of `int32_t`, as `uint64_t`.

Note that the standard doesn't specify these steps, it just specifies the required result.

Comment: "1. Sign- or zero-extension of the value. If the value is signed, then sign extension is used." -> sign-extension of a positive value is zero-extension. So it is sign-extension all the time?

Comment: @Sebastian Sign-extension is used for values of signed _types_, rather than _positive_ values of any type. Values of unsigned _types_ use zero-extension. On x86, the signedness of the type detetermines whether [`MOVSX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd) or [`MOVZX`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) instruction is used.

Comment: According to the standard, the `int32_t` is directly converted to `uint64_t`, there is no intermediate `int64_t` step.  There are no casts in this code either

Comment: @M.M Under the hood C++ compiler needs to choose the correct instruction to extend the value. The standard doesn't specify or require how that must happen, it just specifies the required result. I find these standard quotes here less than helpful. It has been said many times that reading C++ standard one would not be able to implement a C++ compiler. There can be as many intermediate steps as necessary, as long as result satisfies that requirement of the standard.

Comment: The question specifically asks about the standard , your answer describes one possible way of the compiler producing the required result on common hardware. (But even then there is no `int64_t` type involved, your step 1 describes an operation on a register which doesn't have a type. And your step 2 is a no-op)

Comment: @M.M Explain me the magic of `int32_t` conversion to `uint64_t` then, how exactly that happens, without using opaque and unhelpful "congruent to the source integer modulo 2^N, where N is the width of the destination type."

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Your new wording 'signed type' makes it clearer now. I read "signed value" as "has active sign bit" = "negative value".

Comment: @M.M Clarifying for you: explain it to me in simple steps so that I can form an intuitive mental model.

Comment: An explanation of modular arithmetic from first principles would be beyond the scope of comments (comments are not for extended discussion) . Perhaps you could read over https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic  and work on some examples with a smaller number of bits, e.g. satisfy yourself that -1 and 255 are congruent modulo 256

Comment: @M.M You are pedantically correct in each of your comments, however, each of your comments is least helpful, really. I would prefer my own answer. What one really wants to know is whether sign- or zero-extension is used.

Comment: Here's the thing: the mental model where the signedness is changed **first**, *then* the number is widened, seems **equally intuitive** to me. I'm sure the C++ designers had some motivations, derived from high theory, for *this* order, but from where I sit, both orders of conversion make sense. And the result would be tangibly different.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev I am talking about the kind of intuition that comes from training on correct examples, so that the conscious thinking step is eliminated. That is why I say that it helps you _form_ an intuitive mental model.

Answer (score 1):

From the section on *Integral conversions*:

> [`[conv.integral/3]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3) Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo *2<sup>N</sup>*, where *N* is the width of the destination type.

In other words, the wrap-around "happens last".